# setInterval works only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `setTimer` to animate a slide show using straightforward jQuery. I provide the user with a button (in the form of a "DIV" with a button background image) that he clicks to start the show and which then turns into a pause button. The slides are supposed to change every 3 seconds. Here is the relevant code:

```
    playLink  = $('<div id="lbPlayLink"  />').click(function(){
            $(playLink).hide();
            $(pauseLink).show();
            slideInterval = setInterval(function(){next()}, 3000)
    })[0];
    pauseLink = $('<div id="lbPauseLink" />').click(function(){
            $(playLink).show();
            $(pauseLink).hide();
            clearInterval(slideInterval);
    }).hide()[0];
```

The next() function call does the work of replacing the slide with the next one. I have checked out this function and it works perfectly if I call it directly (synchronously), however, when it gets called asynchronously by the `setInterval`, it works fine the first time (3 seconds after I click on the button), but is never called again, even though it should be called 3 seconds later. I know it's never called as I put an "alert" call at the beginning and end of the function.

If I replace the `next()` call in the `setInterval` with `alert('test')` then I can see the `setInterval` is doing what it is supposed to. I can't for the life of me see why `alert()` is OK but `next()` isn't, unless it has something to do with "scope" of functions, but in that case why does it work the first time?

I've tried debugging the code with firebug, but it can't really help with timeout functions like this. Neither Firefox nor IE8 show any error messages.

I've looked through the various posts here and elsewhere on `setInterval`, but can't see anything relevant that I haven't tried already. I've been experimenting now for about 3 hours and it's doing my head in. Can anyone suggest what I can try next?

Comment: What does `next` do or better, can you show us its code?

Comment: Seems to me the next() function is the root cause here

Comment: Matt, you're crazy ;-)  String-based setTimeout/setInterval is significantly slower than raw function passing (because it has to use eval, and eval blows).

Comment: @Neil -- please don't edit your question to remove after you solve the problem.  You should post/choose an answer.  Or delete the whole thing.

Comment: The result can be seen at http://www.trips.elusien.co.uk/slimbox2 (click on example 9)

Comment: Neil, you might want to add that as an answer, and then mark it.  Answering your own question isn't ideal, but it beats leaving this to show up as an unanswered question forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify how I solved the problem:

I took onboard Ivo's suggestion to have a single button (though in the form of a "DIV" element rather than a "BUTTON") and change the class of this button between "lbPlay" and "lbPause" to change the background image and trigger the correct action.

My main problem was that I was unknowingly setting the event on this button multiple times and I believe this is what was causing the strange behaviour.

I got round it by putting the return code from the "setInterval" call into a variable ("ppHandler") attached to the DIV, using the jQuery "data" method.

The new code is:

```
if (typeof($(playPauseLink).data('ppHandler')) == 'undefined'){
    $(playPauseLink).click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('lbPlay')) {
            if ($this.data('ppHandler') != -1) clearInterval($this.data('ppHandler'));
            $this.data('ppHandler', setInterval(function(){next();}, slideInterval*1000));
            $this.removeClass('lbPlay').addClass('lbPause');
        } else {
            if ($this.data('ppHandler') != -1) clearInterval($this.data('ppHandler'));
            $this.data({ppHandler: -1});
            $this.removeClass('lbPause').addClass('lbPlay');
        }
    });
```

Thanks to all who responded. To see the final result go to "www.trips.elusien.co.uk" and click on the "slimbox examples" link and go to "example 9".

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't like the way you wrote the code, it is not very readable, I would rather suggest something like the following (not tested yet, not sure if it works):

The CSS:

```
#slides{
    /* So you can position your elements under the div#slides */
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;

    /* So you can position your button anywhere you like */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

.play {
    background:url(..) no-repeat;
}

.pause {
    background:url(..) no-repeat;
}
```

The HTML consist of the parent `slides` holding everything relating to slides, and the `controller`, basically holds your button image.

```
<div id="slides">
    <div id="controller" class="button play"></div>
</div>
```

The code:

```
(function() {

    //Let's wrap everything in an anonymous function, so to avoid variable confusion

    function next() {
        //Assume this is your code doing the sliding. I don't touch
    }

    var invt;

    function play() {
        //Always clear interval first before play
        if (invt) clearInterval(invt);
        invt = setInterval(function() {
            next();
        }, 3000);
    }

    function pause() {
        if (invt) clearInterval(invt);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#controller').click(function() {

            //It's not playing so it has the play class
            if ($(this).hasClass('play')) {
                $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
                pause();
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
                play();
            }
        });
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line on both:

```
$('<div id="lbPlayLink"  />').click(function(){
```

to:

```
$('<div id="lbPlayLink"  />').live("click", function(){
```